# why is this implementation of Dijkstra's not working?

Tags: java, loops, dijkstra

This is a method i wrote to implement Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm... when I run it, the second for loop is never reached but I can't figure out how to fix this.  I know it has something to do with setting the mincost as MAX_VALUE but I don't know how else to initialize.

```
// method to find shortest path between source village,s, and destination village, d 
public ArrayList<Village> shortestPath(Village s, Village d){
    int[] villageCosts= new int[villages.size()];
    boolean[] wasVisited= new boolean[villages.size()];
    shortestPath = new ArrayList<Village>();
    int counter= wasVisited.length;
    System.out.println("the value of the counter is: "+ counter);

    for(int i=0; i<villageCosts.length; i++){ //initialize to infinity
        villageCosts[i]= Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    //villageCosts[s.getVillageName()] = 0; while(counter > 0){
        System.out.println("in the while loop! the value of the counter is: "+ counter);
        int mincost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int minindex= 0;

        //if the minimum cost in villageCosts i still infinity
        for(int i=0; i<villageCosts.length && wasVisited[i]==false; i++){
            System.out.println("in the first for loop!");
            if (mincost <= villageCosts[i]){
                System.out.println("in the first if statement!");
                mincost = villageCosts[i];
                minindex= i;
                wasVisited[i]= true;
                counter--;
                System.out.println("the value of the counter after the first if statement: " + counter);
                System.out.println("min index: " + minindex);
            }   
            shortestPath.add(villages.get(i));
        }   System.out.println("out of the first for loop!");


        //if minimum cost in villegeCost is still infinity
        if(villageCosts[minindex] == Integer.MAX_VALUE){
            System.out.println("in the if statement that returns null if true!");
            return null;
        }

        //for min index road loop through adjVillages,and calculate village cost of minindex + cost of road between minindex and each adjVillage
        for(int i=0; i< villages.get(minindex).adjVillages.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("in the second for loop!");
            Road b= getRoadBetween(villages.get(minindex), villages.get(i));
            int toll=b.getToll();
            int alt= villageCosts[minindex] + toll;
            if(alt < toll){
                System.out.println("in the if statement in the second for loop!");
                toll=alt;
                wasVisited[toll]= true;
                counter--;
            } shortestPath.add(villages.get(alt));
        }   
    }           System.out.println("out of the while loop!"); //ends while loop 
    return shortestPath;
}
```

Comment: Then you can step through your program while it's running, line by line, to identify weird behaviour. Start by setting an appropriate breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

This line should be changed

```
int mincost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
if (mincost <= villageCosts[i]){
```

It should have been the other way round, you want to find the lowest `mincost`. It should be

```
if (mincost >= villageCosts[i]){
```

**Edit**
Reply to comment

If it does not run through the second loop, check the size of `villages.get(minindex)`. I am not sure what kind of dijkstra it is. I would be even more surprised if it finds out the shortest path. You should probably step back and review your code.

Comment: I've tried that, but it still does not run through the second loop

Comment: @user2648788 try and use debugger in eclipse. Add a breakpoint at that line.

Answer (score 0):

`the second for loop is never reached`

The condition in `if` after the first loop is always true as you are not overwriting `villageCosts[minindex]`...

```
if(villageCosts[minindex] == Integer.MAX_VALUE){  
   System.out.println("in the if statement that returns null if true!");   
   return null  
}
```

Comment: What should I be setting villageCost[minindex] too after the first for loop?

Comment: What do you want to achieve in that loop?

Comment: The first for loop is for the first village being checked as visited